# How to take a value in one column and copy that value to a field on the same record in bulk

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, bulkupdate, xrmtoolbox

We use Dynamics 365 and have a couple custom entities related to real estate.

We have a field in one of our main entities that has been used to set a "Property Owner" using a lookup field, but we're at a point now where Accounts can/should be the "Property Owner". So I created a new field using the Customer type instead of Lookup and am trying to find a way that isn't exporting/importing all the property records we have in order to copy/paste the existing property owner into the new customer field.

I've been trying to use XrmToolBox but can't seem to figure out a solution through that. Specifically, using the tools Bulk Data Updater, XRM Tokens Runner, Universal Search, and can't seem to figure out a solution..

Any tips or tricks that could help me would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
MetaGup

Comment: write a C# console application to update the records

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Bulk Data Updater doesn't allow polymorphic (customer) fields, I'd give [SQL 4 CDS](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/MarkMpn.SQL4CDS/) a shot.